# how to integrate galleria theme into cakephp

Tags: cakephp-1.3

when i load images from database dynamically  jquery was not supported to gallery images  the following error displayed
Error: jQuery(".be-infired").jcarousel is not a function

and its my script given below

$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.be-infired').jcarousel( function(){
  scroll: 1
 });
});

and cakephp code

image("/img/user/".$img);?>

Answer (score 0):

The error means that jCarousel files are not getting loaded correctly. Check the  paths carefully. Also check if you are unloading jquery.jcarousel.min.js anywhere later in your code.